# Laravel - How to make unique two fields using rules request

Tags: laravel, validationrules

In Laravel-8 I have this unique rules request validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //company
        'companyName' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:3',
            'max:100',
        ],
        'country_id' => [
            'nullable',
        ],
      ];
 }
```

How do I make companyName unique in relation to country_id?

Thanks

Comment: you mean each country should have only one company name ABC ?. Which  means Nigeria cant have two companies name  ABC. Is it ?

Comment: @NipunTharuksha -  mean the same company name cannot exist in the same country. For example If someone Registers a company as ABC and select Ghana, it cannot be done by again selecting the same coountry (Ghana). But another country can be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom validation rule for your set of rules.

I'm suggesting that your `Country` has `hasMany()` relationship to `Company`

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //company
        'companyName' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:3',
            'max:100',
            function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $country = Country::findOrFail(request()->get('country_id'));
                
                if(!$country->companies()->whereName(request()->get('companyName'))->get()->isEmpty()) {
                    $fail('Woops, there\'s a country with this name. Type another one, please :)');
                }
            },
        ],
        'country_id' => [
            'nullable',
        ],
      ];
 }
```

Read more about Custom Laravel Validation Rules here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Thanks it works. But how do I add this   ->ignore($this->id)   in order to do the same thing for update record.   I added it add the back but it highlights it.

Comment: @mikefolu, can you explain what you want to do and what you want to get? I am not sure that I understood you fully :)

Comment: What you have done here works perfectly for insert(create) form validation. If I want to use the same thing for Edit(Update) form validation validation, how do I modify the same rules request?

Comment: @mikefolu, hmm, let's say that your edit form has `companyName` field. It should be `required`, `string`, of course, with length from `3` to `100` characters and be unique. Did you use this rule set with my validation function for edit forms? Didn't it work?

Comment: When I trid to use the same thing for update it says it already exists. That why I tried to add ->ignore($this->id)  but it highlights it

Comment: @mikefolu probably you're making validation for it somewhere else, because I don't see any rule for it in `rules()`, only one is my function, but `request()->get(...)` will return value from the form, not from the database and it should work fine. Check your controllers, please :) If you couldn't find the problem, tell me here!